# Grails SqlException for connection URL

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, grails, datasource

I have a Grails app that is throwing an exception when I deploy it as a war. The exception doesn't make any sense, because I don't have the Grails in-memory DB configured in my Datasource.groovy file. Below is the exception and my datasource.groovy file. Can anyone tell me why it keeps throwing this exception? I have run `grails clean` followed by `grails war` several times. Also note that I do have the Oracle driver downloaded and that the app works just fine on my development machine. Thanks.

Exception:

```
2013-07-22 11:41:30,265 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
2013-07-22 11:41:30,265 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource' for connect URL 'jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 2 more
```

DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
    username = "user"
    password = "password"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:DB"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = ""
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:DB"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = ""
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:DB"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the `url = ` or it's just a typo?

Comment: I don't see `jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDB` mentioned anywhere in `DataSource`!! Are you referring any additional config file?

Comment: you are using an h2 jdbc url, but you have an oracle driver - pick one

Comment: @dmahapatro Hey! I think that grails consider this as url default, since he missed the declaration in the production environment.

Comment: I'm embarrassed, Sérgio. No idea how I missed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @grantmc It happens when we use dynamic languages. It's easy to mistype configs like mapping (domain class). So, I've been there too :-)

Comment: @SérgioMichels Thanks, never knew that. I never tried breaking that. but its good I came to know something new. :)

Comment: @grantmc Don't be embarrassed. We would not learn if we do not make mistake. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clean this topic, it needs an adjustment in the production block.

Replacing

```
production {
  dataSource {
    dbCreate = ""
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:DB"
```

to

```
production {
  dataSource {
    dbCreate = ""
    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:DB"
```

will work.